# xubuntu - CPU at 78C while watching youtube videos

Tags: cpu, nvidia-optimus, overheating, bumblebee, gpu

Xubuntu 18.04

CPU: i3-2348m
GPU: gt645m
RAM: 8gb 600mhz-ish ddr3

**The other posts didn't help me, don't mark it as a duplicate**

I do have bumblebee installed *heard if you don't have it installed, you might get worse temps* but when i test it i get [this message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qT7Lq.png)

I installed it using [this](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Bumblebee) and then did the 'update drivers part (but with a much newer driver'

[CPU Temps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T1jdg.png) *sorry about the video in the background, i still don't have a way to crop images*

1. Is there a way to just remove bumblebee and all its files and re-install it again?
2. Should i just re-install xubuntu and re-install all my apps on it, I tried fixing bumblebee multiple times with no success i think maybe i just messed up some files or something.

Might even go back to using windows if i can't get it sorted out :( i really like xubuntu so far *except this part that i am having issues with*

Comment: Please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1067632/edit) your question and put in what version of Ubuntu you are running.  Also, how did you install Bumblebee?  Also, what video drivers are you using?  I have Xubutu 18.04 now with NVIDIA in my system but I don't use Bumblebee.  I only install the drivers from the graphics-drivers ppa.  I also have set up my Xubuntu to use Compton as the compositor as it runs much smoother.

Comment: edited it, i have xubuntu 18.04, bumblebee was installed normally(i guess idk)

Answer (score 0):

Can be the fan/heatsink of the CPU? Maybe is full of dust.
Check Bumblebee [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Bumblebee).

Answer (score 0):

To remove the Bumblebee, it would be just the following:

```
sudo apt remove bumblebee bumblebee-nvidia virtualgl
```

Bumblebee itself has not been upgraded since Ubuntu 15.10 (see https://launchpad.net/~bumblebee/+archive/ubuntu/stable).  It is probably best just to go with the NVIDIA drivers from the [graphics-drivers:ppa](https://launchpad.net/~graphics-drivers/+archive/ubuntu/ppa).  According to NVIDIA's website, your card is supported in the 396.xx drivers.  To set up the drivers run the following from a terminal window:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt update
sudo apt install nvidia-driver-396
```

Reboot the system after the drivers are installed.  There are other tricks that you can try later for smoothing out video play on the internet, etc by like changing the compositor to Compton (these instructions are a little old as Compton is now in the repositories so no need to add the PPA:  https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2144468)

Hope this helps!